# Access dynamic generated content in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to change dynamic content generated by wordpress. What my function should do is, change image sources which I get from the database within a json call. So far so good. But as those images in Wordpress are dynamically inserted, I can't access them via javascript. I do know the on() method to access dynamic content, but as there is no such thing as a click, is there a way to get this content anyway?

Here's the JS:

```
(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '../wp-content/plugins/svgmagic/getsvgimages.php',
        success: function (data) {
            // paths from svg files
            for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
                var splitIt = data[i].guid.split('/');
                jQuery('.attachment.save-ready').each(function() {
                    if(jQuery(this).find('.filename div').text() == splitIt[splitIt.length-1]) {
                        jQuery(this).find('.centered img').attr("src",data[i].guid);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: could you please post your code?

Comment: sure. but I don't think that this will help a bit.

Comment: not sure will help or not, try using this
`time = window.setInterval(function(){if(document.readyState == 'complete'){ /*put your ajax function here*/; clearInterval(time);} },100)`

Comment: How do you want to access your images? Do you want to access them via a click? What do you mean there 'is no such thing as a click'?

Comment: When the page loads, I want to cycle through all my pictures and change their source if it is a .svg image. I don't wait for a specific event. But as Wordpress media-manager seems to build up with javascript, I cannot access those dynamic generated images.